# handling various currency strings pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few hundred thousand rows of data with many different currency forms, some examples being:

```
116,319,545 SAR
40,381,846 CNY
57,712,170 CNY
158,073,425 RUB2
0 MYR
0 EUR
USD 110,169,240
```

These values are read into a `DataFrame`, and I am unsure what the best way (if there is a prebuilt way?) is to just get the integer value out of all the possible cases. There are probably more currencies in the data.

Currently the best approach I have is:

`df1['value'].str.replace(r"[a-zA-Z,]",'').astype(int)`

But this fails obviously with the entry `xxxx RUB2`.

#### EDIT:

In addition to the working answer, it also is reasonable to expect the currency to be important - to extract that the regex is `([A-Z]+\d*)`

Answer (score 2):

Given this df

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df["col"]=["116,319,545 SAR",
"40,381,846 CNY",
"57,712,170 CNY",
"158,073,425 RUB2",
"0 MYR",
"0 EUR",
"USD 110,169,240"]
```

You can use regex `'(\d+)'` after removing commas to get

```
df.col.str.replace(",","").str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
0
0   116319545
1   40381846
2   57712170
3   158073425
4   0
5   0
6   110169240
```

Another more manual solution would be to `split` and `replace`

```
df.col.str.split(' ').apply(lambda d: pd.Series(int(x.replace(",","")) for x in d if x.replace(",","").isdigit()).item())

0    116319545
1     40381846
2     57712170
3    158073425
4            0
5            0
6    110169240
```